# How to get a synchronized Queue(Of T) in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, queue

I'm trying to create a thread-safe queue of Bytes - One thread receives data from a serial port and puts it into a queue, then the main thread reads the data form the queue and acts on it. Microsoft's .Net documentation suggests using [Queue.Synchronized()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.queue.synchronized?view=net-7.0#system-collections-queue-synchronized(system-collections-queue)), however this doesn't seem to work for a Queue(Of T).

Trying the following:

```
Public Class Form1

#Region "Variables"
    Private RxDataUnsafe As Queue(Of Byte) = New Queue(Of Byte)
    Private RXData As Queue(Of Byte) = Queue(Of Byte).Synchronized(RxDataUnsafe)
```

The error I get is: *Synchronized is not a member of Queue(Of Byte)*

This does work if I remove the `(Of Byte)` , which I think gives me a generic queue. I guess this will work for me, but it feels wasteful to be creating a generic type to hold single bytes.

```
Public Class Form1

#Region "Variables"
    Private RxDataUnsafe As Queue = New Queue
    Private RXData As Queue = Queue.Synchronized(RxDataUnsafe)
```

Is there a recommended way to implement a thread-safe Queue(Of T) ?

Comment: Note that in the "Thread Safety" section, the docs for `Queue(Of T)` point you to use `ConcurrentQueue(Of T)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`ConcurrentQueue(Of T)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=netframework-4.8) instead.